# R:plot:text: Changing the colour of text within a plot

Tags: r

I have a plot with some text.
I would like to change the colours within the text string.
I tried:

```
plot(1:10,1:10)
text(5,5,"This is Red",col="red","This is blue",col="blue")
```

But this does not work.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try this with 2 text calls: `plot(1:10,1:10); text(5,5, "this is red", col = "red") ; text(7,7, "this is blue", col = "blue")`

Comment: According to the linked answer use `ctext <- c("This is Red ", "This is blue"); concat.text(5,5,ctext, col = c("red", "blue"))`